# Working with ReactiveMongo (for play framework apps) in 2020

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'v set up and new project of playframework 2.8, and my dilemmas are:

**1.** which dependency should I use:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "1.0"
```

OR

```
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" // dont even think that there is 1.0 for play 2.8, is it deprecated?
```

**2.** up until now I used play-json for serialize/deserialize my objects that I insets or fetch from mongo, for example:

```
object MongoSerializer {
  implicit val InstantFormat = CommonSerializers.InstantSerializers.BSONFormat
  implicit val MetadataFormat: OFormat[Metadata] = Json.format[Metadata]
  implicit val PairingFormat: OFormat[Pairing] = Json.format[Pairing]
  implicit val pairTypeFormat: Format[PairType] = EnumFormats.formats(PairType)
}
```

and in my dbconfig I used `_.collection[JSONCollection]`, but I remember someone wrote that `JSONCollection` is about to be deprecated and there will be only support for `BSONCollection` so I wanted to work with `BSONCollection`.

so as you can see I'm a bit confused, if there is someone who can help me understand what setup should I use and which serialize/deserialize will go best with it I will appreciate it allot. thanks!

Comment: Please, first read the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/json/overview.html)

Comment: @cchantep you right, I did invest more time on the documentation and found it very helpful. I'm all set now with version ```"1.0.0-play28"```. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for the first option because some of my result is an aggregation/customization of different collections. Thus, I will have to write custom BSON/JSON converters myself.